# How do I open one form from another across Projects in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

So I Have 3 Forms **Login**, **Register**, and **Main**.
I want to click on login and then it should launch **Main** and the issue im having is below.

**Descriptions:** I'm Trying to launch Main from Login when I click a `Button` in the UI.

```cs
using Project1

namespace Loader
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void siticoneRoundedButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Injection Successful", "Injected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Main f3 = new Main();
                f3.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Also MainForm = Main]

**MainForm** = Main

The Error is in Login and it tells me, my Form can't be found.
Any help is appreciated.

> The Type or namespace name 'Main' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Did add reference of `Launcher` project to the `Thing` project?

Comment: Launcher is Project1

Thing is Project2 and in Project1 I Referenced Project2

Comment: Based on the first line of the question we have `Thing.Main` and `Launcher.MainForm`. You are trying to access `Launcher.MainForm` from `Thing.Main`. For that to work, you need add project `Launcher` as a reference to project `Thing`, but per your last comment you have quite opposite - project `Launcher` has reference to `Thing` project.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add the other project to the references for this project, if you did. then you have to change the `MainForm` modifier to public(from properties). then you can use it in your project easily.

Comment: @Clayless I think you should change `MainForm` modifier yet. that's gonna solve it. else I have no idea. If you wanna change the modifier of your form, you can go to Properties of the form and change the modifier from private to public.

Answer (score 0):

This question has confused me a bit. Are the three forms in the *same* project, or are they in different projects?

If they are in different *projects* then you'll need to add a reference to the project. In the project your login form is located go to Solution Explorer > References > Right click > Add reference > Projects. Then select the project the Main form is located in. Then, in the Click handle of the login button you'll need to reference the *project* and *form*.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, eventargs e) Handles btnLogin.Click {
    MainProject.MainForm main = new MainProject.MainForm();
    main.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

If you're looking to run multiple forms in the same application I would suggest researching [MDI containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

If this does not answer your question will you elaborate on how you've setup your solution? What projects contain what forms? Are all projects located in the same Solution? Are you trying to run two separate applications; Login is a form in Login app and Main is form in Main app?